# Rendering multiple components on tabs from array with Angular Material

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I'm trying to render some components in a `<mat-tab-group>` from an array of components. This way:

**TS**

```js
...
steps = [
    {label: "Step 1", content: [Step1Component]},
    {label: "Step 2", content: [Step2Component]},
    {label: "Step 3", content: [Step3_1Component, Step3_2Component]},
    {label: "Step 4", content: [Step4Component]},
]
...
```

**HTML**

```html
...
<mat-tab-group>
    <div *ngFor="let step of steps;">
        <mat-tab label="{{step.label}}">
            <div *ngFor="let component of step.content;">
                <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="component"></ng-container>
            </div>
        </mat-tab>
    </div>
</mat-tab-group>
...
```

All works fine, but one of my components now needs to have an MatDialog, so that component looks like this:

**TS**

```js
...
@Component({
    selector: 'app-step2',
    templateUrl: './step2.component.html',
      : ['./step2.component.scss']
})
export class Step2Component implements OnInit {
    constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }
}
...
```

So I've noticed that when component's constructor has an argument (on this example, `public dialog: MatDialog`), my application stops working with this error:

```
Error: src/app/pages/home/home.component.html:40:85 - error TS2322: Type '(typeof Step1Component)[] | (typeof Step2Component)[]' is not assignable to type '((typeof Step1Component)[] & NgIterable<typeof Step1Component>) | null | undefined'.
```

Can someone help me fixing this? I can't find any viable solution to this.

Thanks!